# Twilio get all numbers for account

Tags: python, api, twilio

I've got an account with upwards of 100 numbers in it and I want to get a list of all of them. My issue is that the list() function gives at most 50 and there doesn't seem to be any way to override that. Is there any way either through the UI or API to get an export of all of my purchased numbers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The new way to do this is,

```
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = "{{ sid }}"
auth_token  = "{{ token }}"
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

incoming_phone_numbers = client.incoming_phone_numbers.list(limit=20)

for record in incoming_phone_numbers:
    print record.phone_number
```

Answer (score -1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There's a couple of things you can do here. Firstly, Twilio allows you to [request more of a list of resources by increasing the `PageSize` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/response#response-formats-list-filters). The default `PageSize` is 50, but you can ask for a maximum of 1000.

In Python, you would do this like:

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

account_sid = "{{ account_sid }}"
auth_token  = "{{ auth_token }}"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

# A list of number objects with a page size of 1000
numbers = client.phone_numbers.list(page_size="1000")
```

If you have more than 1000 numbers, then you can still page through the list of resources. The [Python helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install) actually makes available an iterator that will keep requesting pages until you have reached the end of the list. You can see an [example of how to use the iterator in the Python helper library documentation](http://twilio-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/basics.html?highlight=page#listing-all-resources) or below:

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

account_sid = "{{ account_sid }}"
auth_token  = "{{ auth_token }}"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

for number in client.phone_numbers.iter():
    print number.friendly_name
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Why don't you build an export function on the site so we don't have to do this programmatically?

Comment: Also turns out TwilioRestClient has been removed from this library.

Comment: Yeah, this answer was made in 2016 before the latest release of the Python library. It has been updated and the relevant  documentation is available on twilio.com/docs

Comment: is there any update about the latest versions of the python lib?

Comment: @LucasSimonini not sure what you're after here. The documentation for the Python Twilio library is all in the documentation. Specifically, [pagination is described here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python#iterate-through-records), you can use an iterator to automatically page through API results.